# Tradingview pine script returns different values based on displayed chart/timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Hello :) I'm writing a pine script for TV that would screen stocks. It's quite complex, but I've run into some troubles. The issue which I experience it that values returned by script are different if I run it on different stock or even time frame. The script itself is not related to current chart and timeframe, as I just needs to run through some stocks and do a calculations on them finally displaying a table with results.
Below is the very simplified code of it:

```
//@version=5
indicator('Stock scanner', overlay=true)

/////////////
// SYMBOLS // 
s0 = "GPW:ABE"
s1 = "GPW:ACG"
s2 = "GPW:ACT"

//////////////////
// CALCULATIONS //
screener_func() =>

    avg_vol = ta.sma(volume, 7)

    // kapitalizacja
    tso = request.financial(syminfo.tickerid, "TOTAL_SHARES_OUTSTANDING", "FQ")
    market_cap = tso * close

    [syminfo.tickerid, avg_vol, market_cap, ta.sma(close, 200)]

////////////
// ARRAYS //
symbol_array   = array.new_string(0)
vol_array = array.new_float(0)
cap_array = array.new_float(0)
sma_array = array.new_float(0)
[symbol0, avgVol0, marketCap0, sma0] = request.security(s0, "D", screener_func())
array.push(symbol_array, symbol0)
array.push(vol_array, avgVol0)
array.push(cap_array, marketCap0)
array.push(sma_array, sma0)

[symbol1, avgVol1, marketCap1, sma1] = request.security(s1, "D", screener_func())
array.push(symbol_array, symbol1)
array.push(vol_array, avgVol1)
array.push(cap_array, marketCap1)
array.push(sma_array, sma1)

[symbol2, avgVol2, marketCap2, sma2] = request.security(s2, "D", screener_func())
array.push(symbol_array, symbol2)
array.push(vol_array, avgVol2)
array.push(cap_array, marketCap2)
array.push(sma_array, sma2)

///////////
// PLOTS //
var tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 7, 38, frame_color=#151715, frame_width=1, border_width=2, border_color=color.new(color.white, 100))

if barstate.islast

    table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, 'Ticker', width = 5, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
    table.cell(tbl, 1, 0, 'Vol(7)', width = 5, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
    table.cell(tbl, 2, 0, 'Market cap', width = 5, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
    table.cell(tbl, 3, 0, 'SMA(200)', width = 5, text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
    
    for i = 0 to 2
        table.cell(tbl, 0, i + 1, array.get(symbol_array, i), text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.green, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)    
        table.cell(tbl, 1, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(vol_array, i)), text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.green, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)    
        table.cell(tbl, 2, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(cap_array, i)), text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.green, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)    
        table.cell(tbl, 3, i + 1, str.tostring(array.get(sma_array, i)), text_halign = text.align_center, bgcolor = color.green, text_color = color.white, text_size = size.small)
```

So now, as you can see the script calls security functions for Daily timeframe and only for 3 predefined stocks. There are no relations to currently displayed chart/timeframe.

But as a result:

- having displayed GPW:ALR on 1D chart gives Vol(7) = 7144,28
- having displayed GPW:AAT on 1D chart gives Vol(7) = 9616,28
- having displayed GPW:AAT on 4H chart gives Vol(7) = 7144,28
- having displayed GPW:AAT on 1W chart gives Vol(7) = 7144,28
- having displayed NEWCONNECT:WPR on 1D chart gives Vol(7) = 7201,42
- having displayed NEWCONNECT:WPR on 4H chart gives Vol(7) = 7201,42

Do you guys have any idea what might be wrong with my script?

I've already found some similar post: [Pine (Tradingview) Showing different values in different timeframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293999/pine-tradingview-showing-different-values-in-different-timeframe) - and based on this and the general coding advices for Pine scripts, the best approach is to use display timeframe the same as in the script, to avoid any issues. I could live with this (although in the mentioned post the script runs on the chart displayed, while my runs on predefined stocks, not related to displayed one), but why then the difference is even if I use Daily chart and switch between stocks displayed? This shouldn't affect the script.